# Why does't the Feral Kid ever talk?

Tags: character, mad-max-2

In Mad Max 2 (1981), why doesn't the Feral Kid (Emil Minty) ever talk?

Comment: Maybe he had a thick Brooklyn accent.

Answer (score 2):

In real life, kids that end up being raised feral generally don't know how to talk as they haven't had anyone to teach them.

[Here](https://projects.tampabay.com/projects/girl-in-the-window/neglect-feral-child-ten-years-later/) is an article about a real life girl that was raised feral, and her life after being adopted.  Warning, it's pretty emotional.